# Why are there no continued fraction representation for $\pi$ obeying mathematical rules?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, continued-fractions

There are several irrational numbers that can be represented with continued fraction such that a mathematical rule arises in this continued fraction. For example, the Euler number $e$ can be represented as follows:

$$e=[2,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,\ldots]= 2+ \cfrac{1}{1+ \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac 1 \ddots}}$$

It's very fascinating that in the case where the number sequence after the $,$ is chaotic, it does exists a well-ordered scheme when considering continued fractions. Every three steps in the continued fraction, the parameter increases by $2$ and elsewhere the parameter is $1$. Why it is so? Another popular mathematical constant $\pi$ however, does not have a regular structure in the continued fraction:

$$\pi = [3,7,15,1,292,1,1,1,\ldots].$$

But I can see many $1$-s in this series of parameters. May it be that $\pi$ has an irregular continued fraction, but not a very intensive irregularity? Why these structural differences in continued fractions arise between $\pi$ and $e$?

And what is with other mathematical constant like the Euler-Mascheroni-constant $\Gamma$; is there also a regularity in the continued fractions?

I would be happy for any comments and answers.

Comment: There are no short answers to your questions. Recommend the inexpensive and recent http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions

Comment: No such representation is known, it doesn't mean no such representation exists.

Comment: The question deals with the structure of continued fractions.

Comment: I have asked a similar question before, which you might find related. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081429/131263).

Answer (score 10):

If you allow generalised continued fractions, then you can actually. This one is courtesy of Lord Brouncker is 1654:
$$
\frac{1}{4}\pi=\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1^2}{3+\cfrac{2^2}{5+\cfrac{3^2}{7+\dotsb}}}}
$$
This has *very* slow convergence. Apparently people didn't believe it initially. It takes nearly 50 terms for five decimal places of accuracy and nearly 120 for six! (It convergence in an oscillatory manner: above, below, above, below, etc.)

---

If you have a decimal expansion $x=0.x_1x_2x_3...$, then, given that $x$ was chosen uniformly randomly in $[0,1]$, we can see that each of the $x_i$ is uniform on $\{0, 1, ..., 9 \}$. This is not the case, however, with continued fractions. In essence, we can see this best with an example. If you simply start to calculate, say $101/37$, then you'll see that to get a large number in the fraction (in the standard type as you have in your question) you need to have the number that you're inverting close to $0$. Let me explain:
$${101 \over 37} = 2 + {27 \over 37} \ \ \text{giving a 2},$$
$${37 \over 27}  = 1 + {10 \over 27} \ \ \text{giving a 1},$$
and so we continue; however, suppose that at some point we have
$${1003 \over 1000} = 1 + {3 \over 1000}  \ \ \text{giving a 1},$$
$${1000 \over 3}    = 333 + {1 \over 3}   \ \ \text{giving a 333}.$$
We can actually show, with quite a bit of work, what the distribution is: it has density
$$f(x) = {1 \over {\log 2}}{1 \over {1+x}}.$$
(You can either try to prove this yourself or I'm sure you can look it up - in fact, there's probably a related SE question.)

---

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: and are there some mathematical constants with irregular continued fraction behavior? how regularity/irregularity can be explained in this case?

Comment: I've added more detail to my answer. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Does this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law apply to why there are so many $1$'s in the continued fraction?

Comment: Ah, no, that's actually something completely different. It's do to with decimal expansions. Consider this. Pick a number randomly in from 0 to 199 (inclusive). We observe that all the number at least 100 start with a 1, as do all the numbers 10 to 19, as well as the number 1. This gives 111 numbers starting with a 1, out of a total 200 numbers. So if you pick an integer uniformly in $\{0, ..., 199\}$, then there is a probability $111/200 > 1/2$ of it's starting with a 1.

Comment: This fact is applied to detecting fraud in accounting. It's possible to see what a 'standard' number for a form is (say, £3.49), and then work out how likely the first digit is (obviously, my above case is contrived as a stark example). If people have randomly filled in the form, then this can be predicted.

Comment: But it's something quite different, as you aren't taking a continuous random variable. Also, it is to do with decimal (or other base) expansions, not continuous fractions. :) - It's stil interesting though! :)